# Turn SQL table into folder structure

Tags: php, sql, algorithm

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+------------------+------------+
| ID | folder_id | parent_folder_id |  group_id  |
+====+===========+==================+============+
| 01 |         1 | null             | parent     |
| 02 |         2 | 1                | group_id_1 |
| 03 |         3 | 2                | group_id_2 |
| 04 |         4 | 3                | group_id_3 |
| 05 |         5 | 4                | group_id_4 |
+----+-----------+------------------+------------+
```

I need to turn this into a folder structure, where each folder row with a parent_id != null is displayed below the folder with folder_id = parent_id. I need to do this in a sane way, and have no idea how to go about this. After it's created, I'll add items that correspond to the row's group_id.

Ultimately, I need to turn the SQL table into an array that looks like this:

```
$folders["parent"] = array["folder_id_2"] (
    array["folder_id_3"](file 1, file2);
    array["folder_id_4"](
        array["folder_id_5"](file 3, file 4),
        file 5
    );
    file 6
);
```

Comment: What is a "folder structure?" Are we talking about a visual representation, or programmatic (PHP) one?

Comment: I think he means he wants to write directories out to the filesystem following this hierarchy.  Drew, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: An array would be better. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be able to create the array you wanted. But, how about trying alternative solution? Using tree structure. Here is what I would do:

1. Declare `class Folder` which contains `$parent` and `$files` attribute. `$parent` is for referencing parent `Folder` object, and `$files` will be array of files.
2. Iterate database records and instantiate `Folder` objects from each row.
3. Set each `Folder` objects' `$parent` attribute to reference parent `Folder` object.

In this way, we can get the folder structure in form of tree.